# Delete files with a key in a Chrubuntu

Tags: chromebook, chrubuntu

I have a **Chromebook Acer C720P**, I have installed Ubuntu but I am facing an annoying issue, there is not any key to delete files or things, I have to do it manually clicking the items and selecting *Move to Trash*, I wonder if there is a way in which I can set a key or a chain of keys to do this action for me, I will really appreciate any help guys!

Comment: Are you just looking to make a key combination input the `Del`ete key?

Comment: @robobenklein yes, that is what I am looking for since those Chromebooks don't have Supr key.